# PHP iFrame Conditional

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to get it so if two conditionals match then both iframes work, but it only shows one or the other.

```
if ($_POST["age"] === '13below')
{
echo '<iframe id="13" width="80%" height="400px" src="https://domain.com"></iframe>';
}
if ($_POST["age"] === '18plus')
{
echo '<iframe id="18" width="80%" height="400px" src="https://domain.com"></iframe>';
}
```

This can equal the same value if both check boxes are checked. I have reasons for this.

Comment: Pray tell, how could `$_POST["age"]` equal *both* "13below" and "18plus"?

Comment: Both checkboxes can be checked. This is how a user posts content for all age groups.

Comment: Even if there are two checkboxen, **it's only one variable**. It cannot contain two values. What do your checkboxen look like?

Comment: I understood what you were saying, but now I am running into a conditional issue. Any advice?

Comment: Don't drastically change your question, you've invalidated all existing comments and answers. Post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable can't match two values. It can match the first condition, or the second, but not both at the same time. So what you want is impossible in its current form.